# Kibana query exact match

Tags: regex, lucene, elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to know how to query a field to exactly match a string.

I'm actually trying to query like this:

```
url : "http://www.domain_name.com"
```

Which returns all string starting with `http://www.domain_name.com` .

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and ifound that ".raw" fixed it - in your example, try

```
url.raw : "http://www.domain_name.com"
```

Or for newer versions of ES(5.x, 6.x):

```
url.keyword : "http://www.domain_name.com"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, with .raw we can access to the unfiltered/untokenized string!

Comment: in newer version of ES(5.x, 6.x), you should use url.keyword instead, as they have changed to a new keyword type.

Answer (score 50):

Just giving more visibility to @dezhi's comment.

```
in newer version of ES(5.x, 6.x), 
you should use `url.keyword` instead, 
as they have changed to a new keyword type.
```

Therefore, it would be:

```
url.keyword : "http://www.domain_name.com"
```

Comment: Thanks :) Lifesaver!

Answer (score 6):

Exact value is not supported out of the box.

http://blogs.perl.org/users/mark_leighton_fisher/2012/01/stupid-lucene-tricks-exact-match-starts-with-ends-with.html

> Out of the box, Lucene does not provide exact field matches, like matching "Acer Negundo Ab" and only "Acer Negundo Ab" (not also "Acer
>   Negundo Ab IgG" ). Neither does Lucene provide "Starts With" or "Ends
>   With" functionality. Fortunately, there are workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

```
"Cannot change the info of a user"
```

> To search for an exact string, you need to wrap the string in double
>   quotation marks. Without quotation marks, the search in the example
>   would match any documents containing one of the following words:
>   "Cannot" OR "change" OR "the" OR "info" OR "a" OR "user".

Kibana v6.5

Comment: Your answer is very much correct except 1 small thing. "Cannot change the info of a user" would even fetch a document where text would be something like: "Unautorized User Cannot change the info of a user" so anything inside "" is matched as complete phrase. I guess for exact match above answers for url.raw or url.keyword are more correct.

Answer (score -8):

As per you query, it seems fine.

For matching the exact following is the syntax :

`fieldname : string`

and

For matchign the Substring, use wild card (*),

Syntax :

`fieldname : *string*`

Also, whatever the query you applied; is that query is the part of `Query Criteria` of your particuler output component.

So, i suggest you to check whether any of the `wild card` is applied in your search.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nirdesh, but unfortunately there are some irregularities here with the actual functionality.